# mysql won't start, it says Table mysql.plugin doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, table, startup

I've had this problem for several hours, and now I'm just tired..

When I try to start MySql from terminal (mac), i get

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/127.0.0.1.pid).
There seem to be something wrong with the table mysql.plugin, log file says it doesn't exist.
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled mysql on several ways, trying every method i have found googling around. Therefor i think there must be something wrong with the computer - not the mysql software.

Latest install is from mysql.com, a dmg-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're upgrading you should use mysql_upgrade script to install system tables.